# @font-face doesn't install the font on the system or in the browser?

Tags: css, font-face

Is it correct that @font-face doesn't install the font on the system or in the browser?

I guess it's really just a temporarily reference so I can safely reference a licensed font via @font-face?

Comment: it references the font you specify and may download it to the temporary internet files folder but it doesn't install it

Comment: If you are using a licensed font without acquiring a license, you can be penalized for it.

Comment: We did buy but I don't know the license details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about the installation or caching. It's up to license agreement of the font. You can be still guilty if you use licensed font.

Comment: So the license agreement must clearly state online usage via @font-face?

Comment: Usage can contain all of kinds like online usage, applications, games even billboards. I suggest you to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

No, @font-face doesn't install fonts, it just locates them:

[W3C font-face](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule)